# Pycharm 17 theme not displayed correctly

Tags: python, themes, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2 (on OS X) and something strange happened to Zenburn theme from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes. All method names and reserved words are not coloured correctly. Does anyone else experiencing this issue or managed to fix it?

This seem to be relevant for all Zenburn themes I've managed to find on color-themes and GitHub

Screenshot link: https://ibb.co/dJksXv

Comment: Was the behavior previously different? Did it change after a pycharm update, or after re-installing the theme?

Comment: I loaded it up, and some of the hex values used in the scheme on the PyCharm side don't even appear in the xml file (inside the jar).  It could be either it's not in the jar file correctly and PyCharm is using defaults, or PyCharm is not reading the xml correctly. So I don't know if the issue is on the PyCharm side, or on the Color Scheme side.

Comment: I've used this color scheme for java in Idea CE and it seemed to work fine, though I haven't checked it with PyCharm before.

Comment: I know we're a year old here... but did you ever get this resolved? I just started using PyCharm and am in the process of trying to find a Zenburn theme that works :\

Comment: Sorry, no. All themes work nice in VIM though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and adapted an existing IntelliJ theme to work with PyCharm 2018.2. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mspinelli/PyCharm-Zenburn).